# All sound devices disappeared

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I recently ran a routine apt-get package upgrade on my Ubuntu 16.04 install on a Dell Precision 5520 laptop, and I found that all my sound output and input stopped working. I tried rebooting, but that just made everything disppear from Gnome's "Sound" dialog. The output of `aplay -l` is:

```
aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found
```

Whe went through the [long list of possible fixes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure), but nothing's worked.

How do I restore my sound?

Edit: After trying several suggestions in the list of fixes, and rebooting several times, without any success, I tried reverting my kernel, and that fixed it. I suppose there's some bug or incompatibility between the `4.4.0-131-generic` kernel and the Intel sound driver. Reverting to the `4.4.0-130-generic` kernel seemed to partial fix the issue. However, after suspending/resuming the laptop, sound is broken again, although the Sound dialog still shows all the devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've permanently fixed it. This is what I did.

First, I uninstalled all sound components and tools:

```
sudo apt remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio* gnome-control-center
killall pulseaudio
rm -r ~/.config/pulse/*
rm -r ~/.pulse/*
```

Then I identified my buggy kernel:

```
uname -r
```

Mine was `4.4.0-131-generic`.

I then rebooted and held down `shift` to enter the Grub screen, and selected the last working kernel, which was `4.4.0-130-generic`.

I selected this good kernel, and booted using that. I then purged the bad kernel, updated Grub, re-installed all sound packages and marked the current kernel package as hold so a future kernel update wouldn't break everything all over again, with:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.4.0-131-generic
sudo update-grub2
sudo apt install alsa-base pulseaudio gnome-control-center
sudo apt-mark hold linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic
sudo reboot
```

I'm not sure if it's important, but the "Additional Drivers" dialog said I was using the driver "oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms". At various times when I was debugging the problem, that dialog would say I was using nothing or something else. I don't remember what my original working setup used, but my current working setup seems to work fine with this package.

After the reboot, sound worked perfectly again, even across suspend/resume.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me with my dual boot system after windows update (or many things after I did that). This is what worked for me

```
rm -r ~/.config/pulse
sudo apt remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio* gnome-control-center
sudo apt install alsa-base pulseaudio gnome-control-center
```